# How to edit the Query and remove Order By clause

Tags: apache-superset

I picked an entire table as a *Data Source* and picked my fields. The SQL of it returns as:

```
SELECT customer_id AS customer_id,
       country AS country,
       count(invoice_num) AS total_invoices
FROM sales
GROUP BY customer_id,
         country
ORDER BY total_invoices DESC
LIMIT 10000;
```

I do not want this `ORDER BY total_invoices DESC` as it is ruining the entire result. What should I do?

Comment: Which type of chart you are using?

Comment: Line Graph and Bar Graph

Answer (score 2):

I think it always orders by the first metric. If you have multiple metrics, you can re-order them to change which one is used in the Order By clause.

Under Customization, the bar chart also has a "Sort Bars" option to sort the x-axis by label, which might work for you depending on what kind of result you're looking for.